# Почему фоновая музыка не работает на сайте

Tags: html, css, background, site

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой, пытаюсь включить музыку с рабочего стола на сайт, в консоли пишет вот это[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

такой код в html:

```
<audio  src="/Desktop/Chris Johnston & Craig Markva and Jamie Evans — Labradford (OST _Молодой Папа_ 1 сезон_).mp3"
  controls>
</audio>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя путь прописан, неверно. Ты можешь закинуть песню к файлу index.html и указать путь

```
<audio  src="/Chris Johnston & Craig Markva and Jamie Evans — Labradford (OST _Молодой Папа_ 1 сезон_).mp3"
  controls>
</audio>
```

UPD: посмотри внимательней на путь: C:/Desktop я сомневаюсь, что у тебя на диске "C" создана папка Desktop

Comment: Боже,я дурак, спасибо большое)

Comment: Помоему, путь `/Chris Johnston & Craig Markva and Jamie Evans — Labradford (OST _Молодой Папа_ 1 сезон_).mp3` указывает тоже на корень диска C: только без папки Desktop

Comment: https://prnt.sc/117bhgy